# Trouble solving the integral with mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function:

```
\[ScriptCapitalE]=(1/((x - y)^2 + (z - \[Zeta])^2))(c\[Alpha] (x - y)^2 + 
   cz (z - \[Zeta])^2) (((x - 
      y)^2 (z^2 (x^2 \[ScriptA]\[ScriptA] + 
         x \[ScriptA]\[ScriptB] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptC]) + 
      x^2 \[ScriptM] - y^2 \[ScriptM] + x \[ScriptN] - y \[ScriptN] + 
      z (x^2 \[ScriptS] + 
         x \[ScriptT] + \[ScriptU]) - (y^2 \[ScriptS] + 
         y \[ScriptT] + \[ScriptU]) \[Zeta] - (y^2 \[ScriptA]\
\[ScriptA] + 
         y \[ScriptA]\[ScriptB] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptC]) \[Zeta]^2))/
   Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + (z - \[Zeta])^2] + ((x - 
      y) (z - \[Zeta]) (z^2 (x^2 \[ScriptA]\[ScriptD] + 
         x \[ScriptA]\[ScriptE] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptF]) + 
      x^2 \[ScriptP] - y^2 \[ScriptP] + x \[ScriptQ] - y \[ScriptQ] + 
      z (x^2 \[ScriptV] + 
         x \[ScriptW] + \[ScriptY]) - (y^2 \[ScriptV] + 
         y \[ScriptW] + \[ScriptY]) \[Zeta] - (y^2 \[ScriptA]\
\[ScriptD] + 
         y \[ScriptA]\[ScriptE] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptF]) \[Zeta]^2))/
   Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + (z - \[Zeta])^2] + (1/
   Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + (z - \[Zeta])^2])(x - 
      y) ((x - 
         y) (z^2 (x^2 \[ScriptA]\[ScriptA] + 
            x \[ScriptA]\[ScriptB] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptC]) + 
         x^2 \[ScriptM] - y^2 \[ScriptM] + x \[ScriptN] - 
         y \[ScriptN] + 
          z (x^2 \[ScriptS] + 
            x \[ScriptT] + \[ScriptU]) - (y^2 \[ScriptS] + 
            y \[ScriptT] + \[ScriptU]) \[Zeta] - (y^2 \[ScriptA]\
 \[ScriptA] + 
            y \[ScriptA]\[ScriptB] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptC]) \[Zeta]^2) \
 + (z - \[Zeta]) (z^2 (x^2 \[ScriptA]\[ScriptD] + 
            x \[ScriptA]\[ScriptE] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptF]) + 
         x^2 \[ScriptP] - y^2 \[ScriptP] + x \[ScriptQ] - 
         y \[ScriptQ] + 
         z (x^2 \[ScriptV] + 
            x \[ScriptW] + \[ScriptY]) - (y^2 \[ScriptV] + 
            y \[ScriptW] + \[ScriptY]) \[Zeta] - (y^2 \[ScriptA]\
\[ScriptD] + 
            y \[ScriptA]\[ScriptE] + \[ScriptA]\[ScriptF]) \
\[Zeta]^2)))
```

Where the four variables are $\{x,y,z,\zeta\}$; $\{c_{\alpha},c_z\} $ are two constants; $\{m,n,o,p,q,...,aa,ab,ac...\}$ are 18 constant parameters. I have to integrate this quantity and I decided to it in principal values:

```
   \[DoubleStruckCapitalE]=Integrate[
 Integrate[\[ScriptCapitalE] UnitBox[(y - 50/2)/
    50] UnitBox[(\[Zeta] - 1/2)/1], y], \[Zeta]]
```

and then

```
\[Delta]z = 5;
\[Delta]\[Alpha] = 1/2;
 P = (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\[Zeta] -> z - \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x - \[CurlyEpsilon]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. \
{\[Zeta] -> z - \[Delta]z, 
     y -> x - \[CurlyEpsilon]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. \
{\[Zeta] -> z - \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x - \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z - \[Delta]z, 
     y -> x - \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z + \[Delta]z, 
     y -> x - \[CurlyEpsilon]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. \
{\[Zeta] -> z + \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x - \[CurlyEpsilon]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. \
{\[Zeta] -> z + \[Delta]z, 
     y -> x - \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z + \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x - \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z + \[Delta]z, 
     y -> x + \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z + \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x + \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z + \[Delta]z, 
     y -> x + \[CurlyEpsilon]}) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. \
{\[Zeta] -> z + \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x + \[CurlyEpsilon]}) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. \
{\[Zeta] -> z - \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x + \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z - \[Delta]z, 
     y -> x + \[Delta]\[Alpha]}) - (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. {\
\[Zeta] -> z - \[CurlyEpsilon], 
     y -> x + \[CurlyEpsilon]}) + (\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] /. \
{\[Zeta] -> z - \[Delta]z, y -> x + \[CurlyEpsilon]})
```

Then, I have to take the limit for $\varepsilon \to 0$:

```
Q=Limit[P, \[CurlyEpsilon] -> 0]
```

and then again, integrate all of this in $\{x,y\}$:

```
 Integrate [Integrate[Q, {z, 0, 1}], {x, 0, 50}]
```

From all of this, I get a function of the unknown coefficients as a result. This function has Complex numbers. By doing this very same procedure for other 17 functions I get a system of 18 variables in 18 unknowns ($\{m,n,o,p,q,...,aa,ab,ac...\}$). Since all the eighteen equations have complex numbers in it, I get as a result complex unknowns: something must be wrong as these parameters are part of the displacement field of the body I am studying. The displacement field should be a real field. Provided that  [ScriptCapitalE] (the first equation I wrote) is correct, something must be wrong with my procedure or with the way I wrote it in MATHEMATICA.

Comment: What you call "following function" in the firat code block isn't used anymore???

Comment: Yes sorry, the "following function" is \[ScriptCapitalE] in the integral at the second box

Comment: Thanks. The integration of P  didn't finish (MMA 11.0.1 Windows). By the way, your last conclusion seems to be weak: If a result contains Complex numbers the complete expression might be real.

Comment: I have tried but since the result of this integration is a complex number my final solution is complex too. I have tried to enforce the reality condition by adding `Assumptions -> {y \[Element] Reals, \[Zeta] \[Element] Reals, 
  x \[Element] Reals, z \[Element] Reals}` in the integrals but it does not seem to work

Comment: @ Riccardo What is your  Mathematica version and how long does it take to calculate the last double integral?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann sorry I edited the question because I forgot to specify the numerical value of some quantities. I have MAthematica 11 and it takes around 20 min to complete the procedure showed above